# FindViewByID(...) returns null after setting content view and cleaning project

Tags: android, layout

There are a number of questions like this but the solutions haven't worked for me.

Anyways, my main activity has a button that, in its onclick method, takes me to another activity, ViewPowerActivity. I have a layout xml file for it called power_view.xml. Inside that I have some layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/screen_margin"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/screen_margin"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/screen_margin"
android:orientation="vertical" >
...
```

ViewPowerActivity has the basic onCreateMethod:

```
public class ViewPowerActivity extends Activity {
    private final static Powers powers=new StubPowers();

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.power_view);

        Power power=powers.getPowers().get(0);
        View powerView = findViewById(R.layout.power_view);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The findViewById call above is returning null.

If I remove all the code after setContentView(...) and simply return there, it displays the empty layout just fine. I've setContentView, I've cleaned the project, I've tried setting the power view as the main activity, and all sorts of things. What else could it be?

Comment: It will be R.id.power_view. It's a view of xml. Not an xml

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: than you need to get  like this View powerView =findViewById(R.id.layout);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you code it is clear thar **power_view** is a layout ie. xml. So R.id.power_view is incorrect.

It seems you want to access the parent view of that layout. Then do the following.

You have to set an id to the parent LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/parentLinear"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/screen_margin"
     android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/screen_margin"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/screen_margin"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
     ...
```

Then,

```
     View powerView = findViewById(R.id.parentLinear);
```

If you want to take some other view in powerView, you should set id to that view in xml layout and initialize your that view to power_view by **findViewById(R.id.your_view)**

Comment: If this answer helps you, accept and upvote it. Please lemme know.

Comment: This is great! I reference the linear layout itself, and then grab its text views and fill them with information. SOme other errors have popped up but this is a step in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
     power_view.xml


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/screen_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/screen_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/screen_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    public class ViewPowerActivity extends Activity {
        private final static Powers powers=new StubPowers();

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.power_view);

            Power power=powers.getPowers().get(0);
            View powerView = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.layout);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```